# Index Creation on Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb, postgresql-10

I have a issue where i am facing difficulty in creating index.

```
TableName(My_Table)
ColumnName(Repo_id(INT),Data JSONB)
```

JSONB structure:

```
{
   "Property_1":'1',
   "Property_2":'2',
   "Property_3":'3',
   "Property_4":'4',
   "Property_5":'5'
}
```

For one query:

```
select *
from my_table
where repo_id = 1
and Data ->> 'Property_1' = '1'
```

I added btree index **(repo_id,(Data ->> 'Property_1') )**, It worked fine for that scenario.

for other scenarios like

```
 select *
 from my_table
 where repo_id = 2
 and Data ->> 'Property_2' = '2'
```

It is not giving me optimal plan. for that i have to modify previous index as covered index **(repo_id,(Data ->> 'Property_1',((Data ->> 'Property_2')) )** and this gave me optimal plan.

I have more than 100 json attributes in column and for each repo_id in where condition ...json attribute filters will be different. i dont think it will be wise to add all those columns as covered index it will increase index size.

Please suggest how can i efficiently create index on dynamic json attribute filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GIN index and change your WHERE clause:

```sql
create index on the_table  using gin (data);
```

Then use the contains operator `@>` :

```
select *
from my_table
where data @> '{"Property_2": 2}';
```

The condition `where data ->> 'Property_2' = '2'` will **not** use that index. You have to use one of the [supported operator classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) for the index to be used.

If the `@>` operator will support all you ever want to do, using a different operator class makes the index more efficient:

```sql
create index on the_table  using gin (data jsonb_path_ops);
```

With that operator class, the operators `?` `?&` and `?|` would not make use of that index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..Thanks for response. I have filter with repo_id also. So trying to make composite index like using GIN(repo_id,data jsonb_path_ops) also and Data ->> 'Property_2' = ?(i.e. user entered filter).

Comment: @VBAGuy: if you want to include an integer column in that index you need the `btree_gin` extension. But using `Data ->> 'Property_2' = ?` will **not** make use of that index, you have to use the `@>` operator. Depending on how selective the condition on `repo_id` is, it might make sense to try to separate indexes rather then one combined index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..I have btree_gin extension enabled because i am able to create GIN index using both (INT,JSONB) column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...I have create index USING GIN(REPO_ID, data jsonb_path_ops).  then trying to use this query:                                                       
select *
from my_table
where repo_id = 1
and data @> '{"Property_2": "2"}'
and data @> '{"Property_8": "8"}'
; It is going for BITMap Index Scan & Bit Map Heap Scan . I have both columns covered in index. It should not have gone for BIT Map Scan at all.